# Oracle database: Group tables in folders, like Postgres Schemas?

Tags: database, oracle, postgresql, database-design, relational-database

is there a way to group tables into Postgres's schema like structure? We have a Postgresql server we want to move to Oracle DB. We use a lot of schemas to categorize tables. Anything Similar in oracle?  Oracle has Schemas but there is a one to one relation between schema and a user. Schema == User.

Is there another stack-exchange that might be more appropriate for this question?

Comment: Oracle users can access objects in any number of schemas, granted the proper permissions.

Comment: Accessing is no issue. But for creating 10 schemas, we need to create 10 users of that schema name... In postgresql we have a script that runs a test, stores the results and creates a new schema containing views pointing to the results. In oracle we'd have to create a new user everytime, like User Test_7889

Comment: What *exactly* is the problem here? What is it that you know how to do in Postgres that you don't in Oracle? So what if in Oracle you get every schema has a "user"? A "user" doesn't have any privileges unless specifically granted. There's no penalty that I can see.

Comment: Creating a user sounds processing overhead. But from your answer I assume that overhead is negligible.

Comment: Creating a user IS creating a schema in Oracle. There's no processing overhead because they're one and the same thing.

Comment: A few years ago I had to do that with Oracle 10g and it turned out to be quite hard/unpleasant. The reason IIRC was there was no way to say "userA can create objects in  userB's schema", unless userA had very high privileges, like create anything anywhere, as opposed to only in userB. If you need only DML, it may be no problem. If you need DDL, be aware of this and check the oracle docs for your specific version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to create the same amount of schemas in Oracle as you did in PostgreSQL. The fact that each schema is also associated with a user should not bother you.

You don't have to log-in with all those users if that's what you are wondering.

Just create one "application" user, and grant the necessary privileges on the tables you create in the various schemas to that application user.

If you used PostgreSQL's search path feature to avoid fully qualified table names, then you'll need to create synonyms (owned by the "applicatoin" user) that point to the tables in the various schemas.

Comment: Now I have a followup question...

Is there a php or web based interface available in Oracle. We rely heavly on phppgmyadmin (same as phpmyadmin for mySQL).

Comment: SquirrelSQL isn't web-based.  But it's Java, and runs on my Macs, Windows machines, and Linux machines, and talks to any database that you have a JDBC driver for.   It does require that it be installed on the local machine; however, the only complicated part of the install is setting up the JDBC driver.

Comment: @nulltorpedo Oracle Enterprise Manager is the main administrative interface for Oracle and is Web-based. It is integral part of the Oracle installation.